# how to interpret interactions in a four-way ANOVA

Tags: anova, interaction

I have a 2 x 2 x 2 x 2 four-way ANOVA. IVs are *A, B, C, D*.
The four-way interaction is not significant, and only one three-way interaction, *A x B x C*, is significant.
In addition, 2 two-way interactions are significant:
(1) *B x D*
(2) *A x D*
In sum, *D* doesn't participate in any significant three-way interactions, but it's involved in 2 two-way interactions.

How should I proceed to interpret the simple or main effects?

Should I average across *D* and deal with the *A x B x C* interaction first (e.g., *A x B* @ *C1*, *A X B* @ *C2*), and then average across *A* and *C* to deal with *B x D* interaction (e.g., *B* @ *D1*, *B* @ *D2*), and average across *B* and *C* to deal with *A x D* interaction (e.g., *A* @ *D1*, *B* @ *D2*)?

Comment: Your plan of attack looks fine. Order of interpretation doesn't matter much when the 2-way interactions include a factor not in the 3-way interaction. You might need to do it in a different order for presenting to an audience. Your question is so vague it's hard to give more advice than that. Read on here for interpreting interactions.

Comment: It can be quite tricky to interpret a three-way (and you are right to do that first) and I would be a bit hesitant to look at the two-ways until I was sure I knew what was going on in the three way. If you need more help I would suggest posting more information including if possible the data.